# Using pattern matching with ternary if operator

Tags: swift

Is it possible to use pattern matching with ternary if operator?

Consider the following examples:

```
let someString: String? = ...

if let embedURL = embedURL {
    return NSURL(string: embedURL)
} else {
    return nil
}
```

This is verbose. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
return let someString = someString ? NSURL(string: someString) : nil
```

or

```
return case let .Some(someString) = someString ? NSURL(string: someString) : nil
```

But the compiler does not accept that. I know that I could add an initializer to `NSURL` which accepts optional string, use normal `if` statement or even `switch` statement, but I would like to know if it is possible to do with the ternary `if` operator, or whether it will be possible at some point in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use pattern matching in the condition of the ternary conditional operator.
But you can use the `flatMap()` method of optionals instead:

```
/// Returns `nil` if `self` is nil, `f(self!)` otherwise.
public func flatMap<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U?) rethrows -> U?
```

In your case:

```
let someString: String? = ...
let url = someString.flatMap { NSURL(string: $0) }
```

The type of the expression is `NSURL?`, and it evaluates to `nil`
if `someString == nil` or if `NSURL(string:)` returned `nil`.

As @Cosyn noticed, the last line can also be written as

```
let url = someString.flatMap(NSURL.init)
```

Comment: FYI, you can simply write `let url = someString.flatMap(NSURL.init)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use pattern matching to achieve this.

```
return someString != nil ? NSURL(string: someString!) : nil
```

Is as close as you can get using the ternary operator as far as I can tell.